# PHP: Loops that evaluate at the end but do NOT always run once?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

Ok, so I know that "while" loops evaluate at the start and thus don't always run, while "do while" loops evaluate at the end and thus always run, but what if I want a combination: the loop evaluates at the end but doesn't always run?  I can't see a way of doing this without some rather inefficient code, such as:

```
  while($x < $y)
  {
  $x = $x + 100;
  $while = "true";
  }
  if($while == "true")
  {
  $x = $x- 100;
  }
```

...when what I would really like is for the first "while" loop to end during the iteration BEFORE $x surpasses $y.  I suppose I could also accomplish this by an "if" statement within the first "while" loop, but that also seems rather clunky and inefficient.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [How is this of any use?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think this doesn't exist, purely because it is of no use. One of the other loops will always fulfill what you need.

Comment: A more realistic example of what you're trying to do might go a long way in helping us direct you better.

Comment: what is inefficient about `while($x<$y){$x+=100;} if($x>$y{$x-=100;}`?  The couple clock cycles of an added `if` is pretty moot right after a while loop...  It sounds to me like this isn't really a problem, just that you might need some more understand of how to solve different problems with code

Comment: I agree that I need a better understanding of how to solve different coding problems...that's why I came here. :)  TML's idea of storing the previous iteration worked perfectly.  I just didn't know if there was a more direct way to accomplish that.

Comment: It all depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're just looking for a way to "reach back one loop"? A trivial way of doing that is to store the previous iteration, and restore the last "previous iteration" value after the loop body ends.

```
$z = 0;
while ($x < $y) {
  $z = $x;
  $x += 100;
}
$x = $z;
```

Another possible option would be to clarify your intent in the loop condition:

`while (($x < $y) and (($y-$x)>100)) { $x += 100; }`

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I was looking for a way to "reach back one loop," and this code seems to do just that.

Comment: The second answer (or @worldofjr's) are probably actually the better solutions, as they both prevent going too far (saving at least two steps - one loop iteration, plus the final assignment operation).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `$continue` boolean value.

```
$continue = true;
while($x < $y && $continue) {
    // do stuff
    $continue = (/* some comparison such as, $y > 100 */);
}
```

Not too complicated.

Comment: Another perfectly valid approach; as you can see, there are *many* ways to skin this cat without introducing a new looping construct. You just need to learn to attack the problem from a different angle using the tools you have at your disposal, instead of wishing you had a custom tool for each and every job. :)